# Getting null argument when I run any program in eclipse

Tags: java, null

I tried execution in eclipse with two different palindrome programs in java. But when i click Run As Java Application all i get is the below error.
I am getting a different error when i run the same program in command prompt as well

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Eclipse is having an internal error, so maybe try reinstalling it.

Comment: Thank you @ak47 for editing my post, i really dont know how to reply or edit to my own post. :P

Comment: Just as an FYI -- You shouldn't really include screenshots in your question -- atleast not for the code snippets -- the ones displaying the eclipse exceptions are fine

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall Eclipse. If that does not help try to see if your java is installed correctly. Go to command prompt and navigate to the project rootfolder.
Then do the following (trying to compile the program):

`javac Palindrome.java` or `javac Palindrome2.java`

When this does work try to run the programs with either:

`java MyFirstJavaProgram`
or
`java MyFirstJavaProgram2`
to try and run the program you just compiled. Then you can check if the fault is in your java installation or if it is in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and after many checks i found the root cause: it was the JDK that i had imported/selected into Eclipse that was corrupted. Replaced the JDK with a fresh copy downloaded from Oracle and installed, the issue has been resolved.